# How to change the range of the range type?

Tags: ada

Lets say I have

```
    function x return boolean is 
          type range0 is range 1..1; 
        begin 
         canse x is 
          when 4=> range0:=firstArray'range; 
          when 5=> range0:=secondArray'range; 
          when 6=> range0:=1..100;
        end case;
    end x;
```

Basically I would like to change the range of range0 on the go? How may I accomplish this without using the declare block?

Comment: Why is the obvious answer (declare block) excluded? Would converting the declare block into a local procedure be cheating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I would like to change the range of range0 on the go? How may I accomplish this without using the declare block?

Hm...
In Ada 2012 you can use if- and case-expressions, so you could have something like this:

```ada
Type Array_Type is Array(Positive Range <>) of Integer;
Array_1 : Array_Type(1..128);
Array_2 : Array_Type(33..63);

-- your variant-selector
Use_1 : constant Boolean:= True;

-- Your variant-range here:
Subtype Variant_Range is Positive Range 
    (if Use_1 then Array_1'First else Array_2'First)
  ..(if Use_1 then Array_1'Last  else Array_2'Last);

Array_3 : Array_Type( Variant_Range );
```

All that said, this probably isn't the best way to go about it and using a declare-block is very likely going to be more easily maintained.

Comment: Perfect. :) I didnt know you could have expressions like this in Ada 2012. Thanks Shark!

Comment: You might want to look at the new Quantified expressions as well: http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-3-4.html  &  http://www.adacore.com/uploads/technical-papers/Ada2012_Rationale_Chp2_expressions.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You could technically satisfy the stated requirements by converting the obvious way (declare block) into a local procedure :

```
function x return boolean is 

   procedure use_dynamic_range(first,last : in integer) is
      type range0 is new integer range first .. last;
   begin
      null;
   end use_dynamic_range;

begin 
   case z is 
      when 4=> use_dynamic_range(firstArray'first, firstArray'last); 
      when 5=> use_dynamic_range(secondArray'first, secondArray'last); 
      when 6=> use_dynamic_range(1,100); 
   end case;
end x;
```

Because it's a local procedure it executes in the same scope as the equivalent declare block, therefore it can access everything visible within X, so you don't need to pass it a huge parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like :

```
function x return Boolean is
    type Range_Info_Type is
        record
            First : Integer;
            Last  : Integer;
        end record;
    function Get_Range_Info_Type return Range_Info_Type is
    begin
        case z is
            when 4=> return Range_Info_Type'(First => firstArray'First,
                                             Last  => FirstArray'Last);
            when 5=> return Range_Info_Type'(First => secondArray'First,
                                             Last  => secondArray'Last);
            when 6=> return Range_Info_Type'(First => 1,
                                             Last  => 100);
            when others => return Range_Info_Type'(First => 1,
                                                   Last  => 1);
        end case;
    end;
    MyTypeInfo : constant Range_Info_Type := Get_Range_Info_Type;

    -- Now declare the actual type I want to use.
    type range0 is new Integer range MyTypeInfo.First .. MyTypeInfo.Last;

begin
    return true;
end x;
```

A declare block might be easier to understand by this should do the trick.

Note that you cannot write `type range0 is range <expr>..<expr>` in your case since `expr` should be a static expression (see RM 3.5.4)

Answer (score 0):

Another non declare-block answer from Ada 2012:

```ada
Minimum : Integer := Integer'First; --' SO highlight correction
Maximum : Integer := Integer'Last;  --' *same*

Function In_Range(X : Integer) return Boolean is
  ( X in range Minimum..Maximum );

Subtype Variant_Range is Integer Range Integer
with Dynamic_Predicate => In_Range(Variant_Range);
```

WARNING: Though this *should* work, I have not tested it.